# Initial values are not populating in React Form TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, user-interface

The initial value of my react form is not showing up in the TextField when the page is loading.

For testing purposes, I am trying to have 324324324 show up in the ARN TextField.

For reference, I am using Material UI modules.

Unfortunately, I am at a stalemate with this code, and I am not sure where I am messing up. I am a little new to React, so it could be something simple for a more experienced user.

```
const SubscribeForm = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const initialValues = {
    arn: '324324324',
  }

  async function onSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }

  return ( 
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid>
        <Form
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validate={validate}
          render={({ handleSubmit, values }) => (
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <Grid 
            item 
            xs={12}
            className={classes.gridItemRoot}
            >
              <TextField 
                label="ARN" 
                name="arn" 
                required={true} 
                fullWidth
              />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xc={12}
            className={classes.gridItemRoot}
            >
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              endIcon={<SearchIcon></SearchIcon>}
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
            >Subscribe
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          </form>
          )}>
        </Form>
      </Grid>
    </div> 
  );
}

export default SubscribeForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are using redux, if i'm right, refer to this link for reading initialValues

https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/initializefromstate/

If you won't use redux, i think you can place values in TextFields, like this:

```
<TextField    
    label="ARN"    
    name="arn"    
    required={true}   
    value={initial.arn}   
    fullWidth
          />
```

Comment: This successfully does that; however, I am unable to override the existing `initialValues.arn`

Comment: Yes because you'r using const instead of states, then u need to set a function in onChange of form field for setting the states.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `justifyContent: 'center'` into the root style and tell me if it works.
If you want to center things horizontaly you can use it.

```html
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    padding: '0px 12px',
    paddingTop: '8px',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
  ...
```